# GWT Collapsible Panel found in common google services?

Tags: gwt, panel

The GWT Incubator contains [this widget](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=CollapsiblePanel), but it doesn't provide the clean look and feel I am looking for. The Same page does show precisely the widget I would like to use:
A thin resize bar with the small middle arrow icon which is clicked to hide/show a docked panel on the side of the page.

The widget appears on many google services pages, which makes me suspect that it may be a common widget:

[Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/view)

Slightly modified (animated) version on [Maps](http://maps.google.com/maps)

Does anyone where to find or know how to build this widget in GWT.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a [VerticalSpliPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalSplitPanel.html) and overriding the OnClick event? On click you can hide your navigation panel.

Comment: I was thinking of doing either that (resize for free) or creating a custom composite, but still hoping some one will point me at an existing implementation written by someone smarter than me, as I still have a week or so before I need it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Maps and Google Reader are build using GWT. I know Wave is, and it doesn't use the collapsible panel you're looking for... My guess is that this specific widget is not available in GWT but you may be able to find a suitable replacement. Let me know if you do.

Comment: The Google Code Doc reader, at least is built (at least partially) with GWT. Evidence is the page source contains:

    <script language='javascript' src='com.google.codesite.docreader.DocReaderModule.nocache.js'></script> 
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>